# Move a Circle in Android Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

I have a CustomView which should be a moving circle. Previously I saved coordinates from Sensor. And I want to simulate this coordinates in my DetailFragment. The circle must move by coordinates.
Here are my codes;

**CustomView ->**

```
class AnimatedView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {

    private val mPaint = Paint()
    private var xC = 0f
    private var yC = 0f
    private var viewWidth = 0
    private var viewHeight = 0


    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        viewWidth = w
        viewHeight = h
    }

    fun moveCircle(xCoordinate: Float, yCoordinate: Float) {
        xC -= xCoordinate
        yC += yCoordinate
        //Make sure we do not draw outside the bounds of the view.
        //So the max values we can draw to are the bounds + the size of the circle
        if (xC <= 0 + CIRCLE_RADIUS) {
            xC = 0 + CIRCLE_RADIUS
        }
        if (xC >= viewWidth - CIRCLE_RADIUS) {
            xC = viewWidth - CIRCLE_RADIUS
        }
        if (yC <= 0 + CIRCLE_RADIUS) {
            yC = 0 + CIRCLE_RADIUS
        }
        if (yC >= viewHeight - CIRCLE_RADIUS) {
            yC = viewHeight - CIRCLE_RADIUS
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        mPaint.apply {
            color = Color.BLACK
            strokeWidth = 3f
            style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(xC, yC, CIRCLE_RADIUS, mPaint)
        //We need to call invalidate each time, so that the view continuously draws
        invalidate()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val CIRCLE_RADIUS = 50f //pixels
    }
}
```

**Detail Screen (must show in this screen) ->**

```
  class DetailFragment :
  BaseFragment<DetailViewModel, FragmentDetailBinding>(R.layout.fragment_detail) {

  private val args: DetailFragmentArgs by navArgs()

  override val viewModel by viewModels<DetailViewModel>()

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

      args.motion.also {
          it.xCList?.let { it1 ->
              it.yCList?.let { it2 ->
                  val list = it1.zip(it2)

                   for (i in list) {
                       binding.circleView.moveCircle(i.first, i.second)
                   }
              }
          }
      }

  }
}
```

**XML ->**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.erezstudio.motionmonitor.ui.detail.DetailViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.detail.DetailFragment">

        <com.erezstudio.motionmonitor.componentx.AnimatedView
            android:id="@+id/circle_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**X Coordinates ->**

```
[
   -0.016759925,
   -0.3304099,
   -0.18675344,
   0.07422252,
   -0.19154198,
   -0.16520496,
   -0.090982445,
   -0.22985038,
   -0.32562137,
   -0.26097596,
   0.102953814,
   0.083799616,
   -0.105348095,
   -0.4956149,
   -0.15562786,
   -0.14365649]
```

**Full x coordinates are here:** https://gist.github.com/theazat/4b999836a02ce82c22c778f0f9f860c2

**Y Coordinates ->**

```
[
   3.337619,
   3.4094474,
   3.407053,
   3.4094474,
   3.1748085,
   3.1341057,
   3.3256476,
   3.3591676,
   3.3926873,
   3.387899,
   3.2538195,
   3.3136764,
   3.1604428,
   3.2993107]
```

**Full y coordinates are here:**
https://gist.github.com/theazat/d6a7979952af3d7be1fc939c128f3ec7

But in detail screen circe doesn't move. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing this? `xC -= xCoordinate` `yC += yCoordinate`

Comment: Referenced from here -> https://gist.github.com/Jawnnypoo/fcceea44be628c2d5ae1

Comment: I see. Can you post a screenshot? My guess is that `AnimatedView` in XML needs `layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: here is detail screen https://imgur.com/a/dvk6CPq

btw `layout_height="match_parent"` didn't work

Comment: Nothing appears? Does your view have color?

Comment: uhh sorry, I changed background color -> https://imgur.com/a/zciF24X

Answer (score 0):

Call `invalidate()` after changing the coordinates, not inside `draw()`.

Comment: I called `invalidate()` after changing the coordinates but It didn't work.